# C# enter data from database into specific cells in Excel template

Tags: c#, excel

I need to fetch data from database and enter into specific cells in an Excel template. Eg : I only need to enter data in cell -C2, D6 etc.

UPDATE: Right now, I'm entering data from DB into a datatable and searching through the table columns to match with the Excel cells.

```
xlWorksheet.Cells[3, 4] = row["Average"].ToString();
```

All is working fine, except for too much of hard coding.
Is there anyway I can map from DB/Dataset to Excel cells directly?

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` is your friend

Comment: Take a look here before the question is closed: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696864/Working-with-Excel-Using-Csharp
On SO questions need to be specific programming questions, not asking for tutorials or recommendations

Comment: Another option (if working with .xlsx format) is SpreadSheetLight which is a free library using OpenXMl at the core. You install via NuGet. On their home page there is a MSDN style help file you can download. When setting cell values there are overloads for int, string, date etc. Lastly there are many samples out there for this library and on their site. http://spreadsheetlight.com/

Comment: Great suggestion from Karen, and also look at EPPlus.  I was glued to interop before I started using it, but it's quite a bit easier to use